# Android Variable Scope; or, where the heck is my string

Tags: java, android, webview, gps, locationlistener

I'm working on a simple Android app, with a GPS listener and a webview.

I can get the latitude and longitude with no issue. The problem is, I want to put the latitude and longitude into a URL (like myurl.com/mypage.php?lat=57&lon=21)... but the variable the data is stored in is confined to its class. I can't figure out how to declare or create a variable that I can use throughout the entire main class. Here's my code:

```
public class WTest2Activity extends Activity {
    public String txt;
    public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
            loc.getLatitude();
            loc.getLongitude();
            txt = "Latitude: " + loc.getLatitude() + "Longitude: " + loc.getLongitude();
            Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),txt,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"Gps Disabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        }
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"Gps Enabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {} /* do nothing */

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        /* Use the LocationManager class to obtain GPS locations */
        LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
        mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);

        WebView webview;
        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.loadUrl("http://www.myurl.com/page.php?this=" + txt);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "confined to its class". What are you trying to accomplish? Where are you trying to access what?

Answer (score 1):

Your `OnCreate` method is the method called at start of **Activity**. At that time, `txt` is `null`. That's why it doens't show in your **url**. Then, `onLocationChanged` sets the value of `txt` but where are you using this afterwards? **nowhere**!.

you should move what you do in `onCreate` to `onLocationChanged`:

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
    loc.getLatitude();
    loc.getLongitude();
    txt = "Latitude: " + loc.getLatitude() + "Longitude: " + loc.getLongitude();
    Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),txt,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    webview.loadUrl("http://www.myurl.com/page.php?this=" + txt);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add a new line here:

```
public class WTest2Activity extends Activity {
    public String txt;
    public Location location;
```

then, in your `public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)`, try setting `location.setLatitude(loc.getLatitide);` and `location.setLongitude(loc.getLongitude);`

then, you can access your location anywhere with your global variable `location`

Answer (score 0):

Buddy its just small logical mistake in your code. Let me explain. You are requesting location updates then right after that you are loading URL. Now location listening is different thread which is updating value of txt variable. And updating location takes time. And taken time can be different every time. That is why you need to move your loadUrl code to onLocationChanged method.